# How can I export a mesh to UE4 with empty transforms?

Tags: mesh, export, import, unreal-engine

I'm using Blender to import static meshes into UE4. What I would like to be able to do is to 'annotate' my model with various locations - like here is where a character can sit, here is a button to press - that kind of thing. I can parent an 'empty' to my main mesh in Blender (which is just a transform without mesh data) but that doesn't come through the FBX import. What I want to know is how other people solve this kind of issue? Is there a file format that will import this kind of data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Unreal recognise the prefix "Socket_" as a socket location. The prefix gets striped on import. Also note that the position will be in blender translation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: ah thanks! That's perfect

Comment: Perfect but no bounty?

Comment: I'm really sorry, it seems I let the bounty expire. I didn't realise that it had a use by date (this is the first time I'd ever used one) That seems pretty unfair to me but it doesn't look like I have any option to award the bounty now

Comment: No worries... I don't do it for the reputation. But some do and they should have something for their efforts.

Comment: Yeah, this is a reminder to me to watch a bounty question more carefully in future.